# How to split a list of vectors into sublist based on a values of another vector in r

Tags: r

Suppose I have a list of vectors `x` as follows:

```
> x <- list(x1=c(1,2,3), x2=c(1,4,3), x3=c(3,4,6), x4=c(4,8,4), x5=c(4,33,4), x6=c(9,6,7))
```

Suppose I have another two vectors `y`, `y1` such that:

```
 y <- c(3,3)
 y1 <- c(2,4)
```

I would like to split `x` based on the values of `y` and `y1`. For example, 
for `y`, I would like to split `x` into two sub-lists with the same number of vectors (3 vectors in each sub-list)

For `y1`, I would like to split `x` into two sub-lists with different number of vectors, where the first sub-list contains 2 vectors and the second sub-list contains 4 vectors.

I tried this:

```
> z <- split(x, y[1]))
```

but it is not what I expected.

The output should be as follows:

based on `y`:

```
sublist_1 = list(x1, x2, x3), 

sublist_2= list(x4,x5,x6)
```

based on `y1`:

```
sublist_1 = list(x1, x2). 
sublist_2= list(x1, x2, x3, x4).
```

Any help, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `split` to split the list into elements by creating groups to split.

```
split(x, rep(c(1, 2), y))

#$`1`
#$`1`$x1
#[1] 1 2 3

#$`1`$x2
#[1] 1 4 3

#$`1`$x3
#[1] 3 4 6


#$`2`
#$`2`$x4
#[1] 4 8 4

#$`2`$x5
#[1]  4 33  4

#$`2`$x6
#[1] 9 6 7
```

We can also write a function to do this

```
split_list <- function(x, split_var) {
  split(x, rep(1:length(split_var), split_var))
}

split_list(x, y1)
#$`1`
#$`1`$x1
#[1] 1 2 3

#$`1`$x2
#[1] 1 4 3


#$`2`
#$`2`$x3
#[1] 3 4 6

#$`2`$x4
#[1] 4 8 4

#$`2`$x5
#[1]  4 33  4

#$`2`$x6
#[1] 9 6 7
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your great help. Could you please help me to understand why we use `c(1,2)` inside `rep`. Is that for the first and second element of `y`.

Comment: @Maryam It is because we need to split the list into two list. Check output of `rep(c(1, 2), y)` and `rep(c(1, 2), y1)` to know how the lists are splitted.